# How to configure the printer to stop after the page content is finished, irrespective of the page setup?

Tags: printer

I'm printing an invoice from the browser and the invoice size may vary.

I've set a page size of 6 inches width and 5 inches height..

Even if my invoice is just 2 lines  it would take up the whole 5 inches height of paper and roll out..

Can i configure it to just stop rolling paper once the print content is finished, so that i can save paper?

I'm using dot matrix printer and rolling paper..

any ideas?

Comment: What OS/Browser are you using?  What program are you printing from?

Comment: I'm using firefox and Windows and I'm printing from a web application.. I think these things wont affect them.. I'm able to print in the desired font and the desired with.. As i'm using rolling paper, i've set the height as 5inches in the printer configuration.. So even if my total invoice is of just 2 inch then the printer rolls all the sheet of length 5 in.. I want to stop this only :)